# Sms received not the same sent

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to develop an app that send and receive  a sms

my sms's are too long so i used a multi partsend sms method

the sms  is sent successfully bu when receiving the message the character are wrongly printed in screen

please help me

i tested it in a virtual device

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
   ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(keyAsString);
   sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(getPhoneNo().getText().toString(), null, parts, null, null);
```

Comment: SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
   ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(keyAsString);
   sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(getPhoneNo().getText().toString(), null, parts, null, null);

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the phone sending and the phone receiving are using the same character sets?

I'm not entirely sure how to check because I don't know what phone you're using but if the characters look something like this phenomenon then that might be your problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake